# How to apply Morgan's law to parsed string? (transforming the string or with parseactions)

Tags: python, logic, pyparsing, demorgans-law

I am trying to do a program that evaluates if a propositional logic formula is valid or invalid using the semantic three method.

I managed to evaluate if a formula is well formed or not so far:

```
from pyparsing import *
from string import lowercase

def fbf():

    atom = Word(lowercase, max=1) #alfabeto minusculas
    op = oneOf('^ V => <=>') #Operadores
    identOp = oneOf('( [ {')
    identCl = oneOf(') ] }')
    form = Forward() #Iniciar de manera recursiva
    #Gramatica
    form << ( (Group(Literal('~') + form)) | ( Group(identOp + form + op + form + identCl) ) | ( Group(identOp + form + identCl) ) | (atom) )

    return form

#Haciendo todo lo que se debe
entrada = raw_input("Entrada: ")
try:
    print fbf().parseString(entrada, parseAll=True)
except ParseException as error: #Manejando error
    print error.markInputline()
    print error
print
```

Now I need to convert the negated forumla ~(form) acording to the Monrgan's Law, The BNF of Morgan's Law its something like this:

```
~((form) V (form)) = (~(form) ^ ~(form))
~((form) ^ (form)) = (~(form) V ~(form))
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgans_laws

Parsing must be recursive; I was reading about Parseactions, but I don't really understand I'm new to python and very unskilled.

Can somebody help me on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Juan Jose -

You are asking for a lot of work on the part of this audience, whether you realize it or not.  Here are some suggestions on how to make progress on this problem:

- Recognize that parsing the input is only the first step in this overall program. You can't just write any parser that gets through the input, and then declare yourself ready for the next step. You need to anticipate what you will do with the parsed output, and try to parse the data in such a way that it readies you to take the next step - which in your case is to do some logical transformations to apply DeMorgans Laws. In fact, you may be best off working backwards - assume you have a parser, what would you need your transformation code to work with, how would an expression look, and how would you perform the transform itself?  This will naturally structure your thinking to the application domain, and give you a target result format when you start writing the parser.
- When you start to write your parser, look at other pyparsing examples that do similar tasks, such as SimpleBool.py on the pyparsing wiki. See how they parse the input to create a set of evaluatable objects, which can then be acted upon in the application domain (whether it is to evaluate them, transform them, or whatever).  Think about what kind of objects you want to create in your parser that will work with the transformation methods you outlined in the last step.
- Take time to write a BNF for the syntax you will parse.  Write out some sample test strings that you would parse to help you anticipate syntax issues.  Is "~~p ^ q V r" a valid string? Can identifiers be multiple characters, or will you restrict to just single characters (single will be easier to work with at the beginning, and you can expand it later easily)? Keep your syntax simple if you can, such as just supporting ()'s for grouping, instead of any matched pair of ()'s, []'s, or {}'s.
- When you implement your parser, start with simple test cases first and work your way up. You may have to backtrack a bit if you find that you made some assumptions early on that more complicated strings don't support, but that's pretty typical for most programming projects.
- As an implementation tip, read up on using the operatorPrecedence helper, as it is specifically designed for these types of parsing jobs.  Look at how it is used in SimpleBool.py to create an object hierarchy that mirrors the structure of the input string. Then think about what objects would do in your transformation process.

Good luck!